# Vue login page without other elements

Tags: vuejs3

I have an application that needs to have a login page without the navbar/sidebar and footer. It should just be the login page being displayed once the user is not signed in. However, in my `App.vue` using the `<RouterView/>` component it renders the other components as well around the `Login.vue` page. How should I structure my app to allow for the `Login.vue` to be displayed by itself and not render the other components?

```
<template>
  <main>
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <Sidebar />
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="main__content__wrapper">
      <!-- header -->
      <Topbar />
      <div class="main__body">
        <!-- Body -->
        <RouterView/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

I tried to add the login page as a separate component in the app.vue but that still didn't yield expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slots in vue. Here is example.
here is router index.js file

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    }
```

Here is Login File

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
    ...Login..
</template>

<style></style>
```

here is home file

```
<script setup>
import NavAndHeader from '../components/NavAndHeader.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <NavAndHeader>
    ....HomeContent...
  </NavAndHeader>
</template>
```

here is nav and header file from component

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
    ...hello- nav and header...
    <slot></slot>
    ....footer...
</template>
```

I think this solution will fix your problem please leave a comment if you want some modification.

#### Update :

Here is App.vue

```
<script setup>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <RouterView />
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: What would the App.vue look like